# Wordpress and Multi page form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have WordPress website and I want to create multi page form (2 page) using `$_SESSION`

Also I use child theme.

So I have created 2 page templates ( for first and second page). And use `first-template.php` for first page, `second-page.php` for second page

First page

```
<?php
//Session starts here
session_start();
?>

...
<form action="http://localhost/mysite/secondpage/" method="post">
<label>Full Name :</label><br />
<input name="name" type="text" required>

<input  type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

But when I try to send info to second page, I get 'Page not found error', but page http://localhost/mysite/secondpage/ is exist.

Also if I enter http://localhost/mysite/secondpage/ ( browser) - I get second page, but I can't get it using form action

Comment: go throgh this link : https://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two page form you do not want to use SESSION you get variables in second page.

see below code.

**first-template.php**

```
<form action="http://localhost/mysite/secondpage/" method="post">
    <label>Full Name :</label><br />
    <input name="name" type="text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

**second-page.php**

```
if( $_POST ) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

**This code is tested and work perfect.**